# Non-vanishing Taylor coefficients and Poincaré series

Tags: analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm studying these algebraic numbers in the table below and have succesfully shown what i wanted with the given values I had.

The table is found in the book "The 1-2-3 of Modular Forms" by Jan Hendrik Bruinier, Gerard van der Geer, Günter Harder and Don Zagier.

I am looking for a way to calculate more numbers or/and just more values for other discriminants (-31,-35,-39,-40,-43,...).

I hope someone can help.

[Table of algebraic numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y44lv.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use MathJax to edit your question https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.  Also you may want to write down your attempt to solve the problem

Comment: Please try to give more background information to the given situation, which is by the way pretty near to a Ph. D. research project, so please try to give a fair share of the amount of work and informatioin between the known and the expected matter. You not even specify the page in the book, well, i had the book in my hands, it is page 87, but the involved objects are not easily introduced, and trying to figure them out, i saw the information is spread around the many pages of the beautiful article of Professor Don Zagier. So please reformulate and use LaTeX, as i said, a fair share...